# Logback configuration on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logback

I am using Logback on tomcat (7.0.37). I want to config logback in which it can write web-accessible log files for me but i can even config it to write on console. I cannot format the log message on the console. It always return me with the default format and an exception.

`%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n`

Here are my logback-access.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />

    <appender name="RootFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>testing</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>testing.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>12</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
              <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RootConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-6level- %logger{36}: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender-ref ref="RootFileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RootConsoleAppender"/>
</configuration>
```

With this config, i get exception every time when there are http request to my server as below:

```
18:08:19,951 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[RootConsoleAppender] - Appender [RootConsoleAppender] failed to append. java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
    at java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout.doLayout(PatternLayout.java:60)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder.doEncode(LayoutWrappingEncoder.java:134)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeOut(OutputStreamAppender.java:188)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:212)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:182)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logback-access is for access logs. Logback-access has different intent than logback-classic. Thus, in a logback-access configuration file you need to use `PatternLayoutEncoder` from the "ch.qos.logback.**access**" package not "ch.qos.logback.**classic**.encoder" package.

For example, write:

```
<appender name="RootConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.access.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <pattern>%clientHost %l %user %date "%r" %statusCode %bytesSent</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

Please also refer to list conversion words available for [**logback-access** PatternLayout](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#AccessPatternLayout).

Comment: Better yet, don't set the `class` attribute. It works with just `<encoder>`.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this topic while looking for a solution for an exception

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender - Appender failed to append. java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
```

and this seems to be long-known issue, reported here: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/pull/185

**LONG STORY SHORT**

The `AsyncAppender` does not work for `AccessEvent` which is **default access log for tomcat**.